# How to openmp parallelize for loop that increments two variables

Tags: openmp

As a first step into OpenMP I set myself a challenge to parallelize some matrix decomposition algorithm. I picked Crout with pivoting, source can be found here:
http://www.mymathlib.com/c_source/matrices/linearsystems/crout_pivot.c

At the bottom of that decomposition function there's an outer for loop that walks over i and p_row at the same time. Of course OpenMP is as confused as I am when looking at this and refuses to do anything with it.

After wrapping my mind around it I think I got it untangled into readable form:

```
p_row = p_k + n;
for (i = k+1; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = k+1; j < n; j++) *(p_row + j) -= *(p_row + k) * *(p_k + j);
    p_row += n;
}
```

At this point serial run still comes up with the same result as the original code.
Then I add some pragmas, like this:

```
p_row = p_k + n;
#pragma omp parallel for private (i,j) shared (n,k,p_row,p_k)
for (i = k+1; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = k+1; j < n; j++) *(p_row + j) -= *(p_row + k) * *(p_k + j);
#pragma omp critical
    p_row += n;
#pragma omp flush(p_row)
}
```

Yet the results are essentially random.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your adaptation of original code, but your program has several problems.

`#pragma omp parallel for private (i,j) shared (n,k,p_row,p_k)`
Default behavior is to have vars declared outside of scope shared, so the shared declaration is useless.
But these var should *not* be shared and rendered private.
n is unchanged during iterations, so better have a local copy
ditto for k and p_k
p_row is modified, but you **really want** several copies of p_row. This what will insure a proper parallel processing, so that each thread processes different rows. The problem is to compute p_row value in the different threads.

In the outer loop, iteration 0 will use p_row, second iteration p_row+n, iteration l p_row+l*n. Your iterations will be spread over several threads. Assume each thread processes m iterations. Thread 0 will process i=k+1 to i=m+(k+1) and p_row to p_row+m*n, thread 1 i=m+1+(k+1) to i=2m+(k+1) and p_row+n*(m+1) to p_row+2*m*n, etc. Hence you can compute the value that should have p_row at the start of the loop with the value of i.
Here is a possible implementation

```
p_row = p_k + n;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) firstprivate(n, k, p_row, p_k)
// first private insures initial values are kept
{ 
  for (i = k+1, p_row=p_row+(i-(k+1))*n; i < n; i++, p_row += n) {
    for (j = k+1; j < n; j++) 
       *(p_row + j) -= *(p_row + k) * *(p_k + j);
}
```

p_row incrementation is in the for loop. This should continue to work in a sequential environment.

Critical is useless (and was buggy in your previous code). Flush is implicit at the end of a parallel section (and the pragma is just "omp flush").

Comment: Yes, I was starting to think along the same lines, having p_row private and set properly for each loop iteration. Wasn't aware of firstprivate, thanks for that. However, my first attempt at p_row=p_row+(i-(k+1))*n is segfaulting and I want to understand why.